# CNN-LSTM performance identical to LSTM, is there a mistake in my code? (Pytorch)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to recreate the models from a study in which CNN-LSTM outperformed LSTM, but my CNN-LSTM produces nearly identical results to the LSTM. So it seems like the addition of the convolutional layers is not doing anything. The study describes the CNN-LSTM model like this:

> The model is constructed by a single LSTM layer and two CNN layers. To form the CNN part, two 1D convolutional neural networks are stacked without any pooling layer. The second CNN layer is followed by a Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU) activation function. Each of the flattened output of the CNN’s ReLU layer and the LSTM layer is projected to the same dimension using a fully connected layer. Finally, a dropout layer is placed before the output layer.

Did I make a mistake in the implementation? The results of my CNN-LSTM are almost exactly the same as when I use the LSTM on its own. The LSTM on its own is the exact same code as below, just without the two conv1d layers and without the ReLu activation function.

```
class CNN_LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, seq_len, params, output_size):
        super(CNN_LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.n_hidden = params['lstm_hidden']        # neurons in each lstm layer
        self.seq_len = seq_len                       # length of the input sequence
        self.n_layers = 1                            # nr of recurrent layers in the lstm
        self.n_filters = params['n_filters']         # size of filter in cnn
        self.c1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=params['n_filters'], kernel_size=1, stride=1) 
        self.c2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=params['n_filters'], out_channels=1, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=input_size,         # nr of input features
            hidden_size=params['lstm_hidden'],       
            num_layers=1
        )
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=seq_len*params['lstm_hidden'], out_features=params['dense_hidden'])
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=.4)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=params['dense_hidden'], out_features=output_size) # output_size = nr of output features  

    def reset_hidden_state(self):
        self.hidden = (
            torch.zeros(self.n_layers, self.seq_len, self.n_hidden).to(device=device),
            torch.zeros(self.n_layers, self.seq_len, self.n_hidden).to(device=device),
        )
    def forward(self, sequences):
        out = self.c1(sequences.view(len(sequences), 1, -1))
        out = self.c2(out.view(len(out), self.n_filters, -1))
        out = F.relu(out)
        out, self.hidden = self.lstm(
            out.view(len(out), self.seq_len, -1),
            self.hidden
        )
        out = self.flatten(out)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

[Source](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/22/3/1060/htm#B24-sensors-22-01060) for the study I am using.